# Performance-wise - canvas vs base URI vs image

Tags: javascript, image, performance, canvas, base-url

I'm creating a color wheel (picker) and I want to know the fastest most efficient way to display the color wheel. I'm currently using JavaScript to generate it with a canvas. I think the other options are an actual image or data URI. If there is a faster way please let me know.

What's the fastest most efficient way to show the color picker?

Color Wheel using JavaScript / canvas

#### JSFiddle

```js
var colorDisc = document.getElementById('surface'),
  colorDiscRadius = colorDisc.offsetHeight / 2;

var drawDisk = function(ctx, coords, radius, steps, colorCallback) {
    var x = coords[0] || coords, // coordinate on x-axis
      y = coords[1] || coords, // coordinate on y-axis
      a = radius[0] || radius, // radius on x-axis
      b = radius[1] || radius, // radius on y-axis
      angle = 360,
      rotate = 0,
      coef = Math.PI / 180;

    ctx.save();
    ctx.translate(x - a, y - b);
    ctx.scale(a, b);

    steps = (angle / steps) || 360;

    for (; angle > 0; angle -= steps) {
      ctx.beginPath();
      if (steps !== 360) ctx.moveTo(1, 1); // stroke
      ctx.arc(1, 1, 1, (angle - (steps / 2) - 1) * coef, (angle + (steps / 2) + 1) * coef);

      if (colorCallback) {
        colorCallback(ctx, angle);
      } else {
        ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
        ctx.fill();
      }
    }
    ctx.restore();
  },
  drawCircle = function(ctx, coords, radius, color, width) { // uses drawDisk
    width = width || 1;
    radius = [
      (radius[0] || radius) - width / 2, (radius[1] || radius) - width / 2
    ];
    drawDisk(ctx, coords, radius, 1, function(ctx, angle) {
      ctx.restore();
      ctx.lineWidth = width;
      ctx.strokeStyle = color || '#000';
      ctx.stroke();
    });
  };

if (colorDisc.getContext) {
  drawDisk( // HSV color wheel with white center
    colorDisc.getContext("2d"), [colorDisc.width / 2, colorDisc.height / 2], [colorDisc.width / 2 - 1, colorDisc.height / 2 - 1],
    360,
    function(ctx, angle) {
      var gradient = ctx.createRadialGradient(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0);
      gradient.addColorStop(0, 'hsl(' + (360 - angle + 0) + ', 100%, 50%)');
      gradient.addColorStop(1, "#FFFFFF");

      ctx.fillStyle = gradient;
      ctx.fill();
    }
  );
  drawCircle( // gray border
    colorDisc.getContext("2d"), [colorDisc.width / 2, colorDisc.height / 2], [colorDisc.width / 2, colorDisc.height / 2],
    '#555',
    3
  );
}
```

```html
<canvas id="surface" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
```

Comment: Html5 canvas is reasonably fast at rendering something as simple as a color wheel so you're probably trying to optimize something that doesn't need optimizing. If it were me, I'd download & draw an image of a colorwheel -- and not look back for further optimizations there. :-)

Comment: @markE Thanks! I never know whether I'm trying too hard for the nitty gritty stuff. It seems like I always end up doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think an image would be faster, but it would be difficult to resize it without getting all kinds of scaling artifacts. So I would go with canvas.

However, there is a third option that I think is worth considering: angular gradient in CSS. Here is a way to do it with existing features: https://css-tricks.com/conical-gradients-css/

Comment: So using pure css is fastest?

Comment: I am only saying it's worth considering. I would err on the side of code maintainability and use canvas anyway. I mean, how slow can it be? Besides, you can cache the result for a specific combination of parameters as a data URL.